# Unable to update java 1.8 as i have 1.9 also installed

Tags: java

I have multiple versions of java installed (1.6,1.7,1.8 and 9) in my MAC. Now i am trying to update Java 8 to the latest update and i am running into  below error. How do i  update java 8 to the latest version without uninstalling java 9?

```
"You are trying to install 1.8.162.01, however 9.0.1.0.11 is already installed.Visit java.com/newerversionexists for more information."
```

Comment: what's your OS version ? [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141168/is-it-possible-to-update-java7-without-first-uninstalling-java8) might be relevant

Comment: how do you update your java 1.8 version?

Comment: I am using MAC version 10.11.6 EI Captain

Comment: I am trying to update using patch .dmg file which i downloaded from oracle site

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, as Mac itself is a Linux you can download the compressed binary version of java 1.8*.tar.gz whichever you want , untar it in a directory, create a bashrc file and set the environment variables JAVA_HOME, PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point to the 1.8 java binaries.

This will work.